# Dependently typed 'ZipVector' Applicatives

Tags: haskell, types, vector, dependent-type

I've made myself a "`ZipVector`" style `Applicative` on finite `Vector`s which uses a sum type to glue finite vectors to `Unit`s which model "infinite" vectors.

```
data ZipVector a = Unit a | ZipVector (Vector a)
             deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor ZipVector where
  fmap f (Unit a)  = Unit (f a)
  fmap f (ZipVector va) = ZipVector (fmap f va)

instance Applicative ZipVector where
  pure = Unit
  Unit f   <*> p        = fmap f p
  pf       <*> Unit x   = fmap ($ x) pf
  ZipVector vf <*> ZipVector vx = ZipVector $ V.zipWith ($) vf vx
```

This will probably be sufficient for my needs, but I idly wanted a "Fixed Dimensional" one modeled on the applicative instances you can get with dependently typed "Vector"s.

```
data Point d a = Point (Vector a) deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor (Point d) where
  fmap f (Point va) = Point (fmap f va)

instance Applicative Point where
  pure = Vector.replicate reifiedDimension
  Point vf <*> Point vx = Point $ V.zipWith ($) vf vx
```

where the `d` phantom parameter is a type-level `Nat`. How can I (if it's possible) write `reifiedDimension` in Haskell? Moreover, again if possible, given `(Point v1) :: Point d1 a` and `(Point v2) :: Point d2 a` how can I get `length v1 == length v2` can I get `d1 ~ d2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I (if it's possible) write `reifiedDimension` in Haskell?

Using `GHC.TypeLits` and `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
instance SingI d => Applicative (Point d) where
  pure = Point . Vector.replicate reifiedDimension
    where reifiedDimension = fromInteger $ fromSing (sing :: Sing d)
  ...
```

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924782/converting-a-type-level-natural-number-into-a-regular-number/12925482#12925482) for a full example.

> Moreover, again if possible, given `(Point v1) :: Point d1 a` and `(Point v2) :: Point d2 a` how can I get `length v1 == length v2` can I get `d1 ~ d2`?

With `Data.Vector`, no. You'd need a vector type that encodes the length in the type. The best you can do is to maintain this yourself and encapsulate it by not exporting the `Point` constructor.

Comment: Do you mean to say having a smart constructor like `toP :: Vector a -> Point d a` which reflects the `d :: Sing (Vector.length v)`? I've been trying to get that to work but it fails and I can't yet figure out exactly what the type errors are saying.

Comment: When I try re-reifying that with something like `pLen :: SingI d => Point d a -> Sing d; pLen _ = sing` GHC complains that there's `No instance for (SingI Nat d0) arising from a use of pLen`.

Comment: Also, why include the `Maybe` when a function like http://hpaste.org/86438 seems to work?

Comment: @tel: What expression are you trying to evaluate? Adding `Maybe` ensures that the length in the type matches the actual length. Wouldn't be much of a point using a smart constructor if you could just use any old vector.

Comment: I'd like fmap pLen . toP === Just . V.length

Comment: Oh! I see. The types are already unified and erased by the time the vector is created, so the 'd' types will already by identified and without the Maybe it'll just go through without checking.

Comment: @tel: Yes, the problem is that you can't compose `fmap pLen . toP` without knowing statically which type level length should go in the middle. `fmap pLen (toP ... :: Maybe (Point 3 Int))` etc. will work.